# OBJECTIVE-C: PushViewController with UIImage doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to pass a UIImage from a First View Controller to Second View Controller, but this doesn't appear in Second View. Why?

My code in FirstController.m:

```
SecondController *second = (SecondController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBSecondController"];

second.imgCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

My code in SecondController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgCard;
```

My code in SecondController.m:

```
@implementation SecondController 

@synthesize imgCard;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If image that you want to set on your ImageView is in your `Assets.xcassets`  or in your project folder ,than you don't need to pass image in prapare for sague just use as  below;

```
imgCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

in FirstController.m:

```
SecondController *second= (SecondController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBSecondController"];

second.imageVar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

in SecondController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imgCard;
@property   UIImage *imageVar;
```

in SecondController.m:

```
@implementation SecondController 

@synthesize imageVar,imgCard;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
 imagCard.image = imageVar;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is the solution :) @Subhash Sharma

Answer (score 2):

`imgCard` will be `nil` until the second view controller's view has been loaded. This doesn't happen until you push the view controller. A view controller's view isn't created, and the outlets aren't connected, until needed.

You have two options.

- Set the image view's image after the `pushViewController` call (not sure if that will cause a visual glitch)
- Add an `image` property to `SecondController` and set that. In `viewDidLoad` of `SecondController`, set `imgCard.image = self.image;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line of code is wrong. The correct way to init your second view controller is :

```
SecondController *second = (SecondController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBSecondController"];
second.imgCard.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
...
```

Comment: Do not set the image directly in Second's imageView. Pass the image only. And in SecondController viewDidLoad set to the imageView.